# JFrog Artifact free tier storage limit of 2GB can be reused?

Tags: artifactory

I'm using JFrog Artifact's free tier plan for my development environment. In that, I've reached the monthly quota for storage of 2GB. I've deleted some old artifacts to save some space and use the Artifact again, but it still showing this message:

> You have reached your monthly quota for Storage. To enjoy unlimited
> usage, Upgrade

So, I just want to know is the 2GB total for a month or can we use the 2GB storage for a month by deleting the older versions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The storage limit in the free tier is for the total storage used - not on a per month basis.
You can clean up older versions to free up space if needed or Upgrade to a paid subscription where you can utilize as much storage as you would like (for a fee).

When deleting artifacts make sure to clear the trash can as well.

Comment: Thanks. The warning is still there, but I can continue uploading the artifacts. And, thanks for the information about the trash. I haven't noticed that before.